# Node.js connect to ftp and download files

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, ftp, connection

Hello i downloaded this npm module to connect to my ftp :  [node-ftps](https://github.com/Atinux/node-ftps)

**connection class**

```
var FTPS = require('ftps');
var ftps = new FTPS({
  host: 'myhost',
  username: 'user',
  password: 'mypw',
  protocol: 'ftp'
});

ftps.exec(function (err, res) {
  console.log();
});
```

how can i check if the connection was successful and how can  i get all files from  my path!

tryed to add an file but get an error i didn't even know if im connected

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would advice you to try `node-ftp` which supports `ftps` too, Although `node-ftps` does the same work, it lacks good documentation and examples.

Checkout here,

https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp

To setup a connection and to access it features, All you need to do is to download a node wrapper called `ftp-client` which is developed exclusively for the `node-ftp` module.

You can install this wrapper by issuing the below command,

```
npm install ftp-client
```

To initialize it use the below command,

```
var ftpClient = require('ftp-client'),
client = new ftpClient(config, options);
```

And you can find a complete example code here which will walk you through how we can connect to a server, and simultaneously upload all files from the `test` directory, overwriting only older files found on the server, and download files from `/public_html/test directory`.

https://github.com/noodny/node-ftp-client#examples

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah tahts nice thank u , and and least can i use raw cmd comands like ls -lh ? :)

Comment: both unmaintained, ftp-client cannot download a single file, just whole directories

Comment: getting error Cannot find module '../lib/client.js'

Comment: @Sudhir Check your NodeJS version and try installing a compatible version of `node-ftp` as per the documentation.

Comment: I have corrected it but getting some other error like getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Answer (score 6):

I have recently tried `node-ftp` and found that is has issues connecting to some newer servers. Particularly I had no ability to connect to a server version `SSH-2.0-1.82_sshlib Globalscape`

`ssh2-sftp-client` worked for me. Pass a `debug:yourDebugFunction` parameter in the connect options for good debugging output.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client

````
let sftp = new Client();
 
sftp.connect({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: '8080',
  username: 'username',
  password: '******'
}).then(() => {
  return sftp.list('/pathname');
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data, 'the data info');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err, 'catch error');
});```
````

Comment: Did you manage to download a file from an ftp and not sftp with this package?