# Download file from ftp through node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I have a ftp server in my network with my nodejs server.
The nodejs server hosts a website and i want users of that website to be able to download certain files of the ftp server.
How can this be done?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to ftp in node?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js connect to ftp and download files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437453/node-js-connect-to-ftp-and-download-files)

Comment: i have no problem connecting to the ftp server and im also able to download to my local machine(the webserver). My problem is that i have no idea how i get the file directly to someone requesting it via http...